# Magento addAttributeToFilter with Multiple Select

Tags: magento, addattribute

I'm having troubles using addAttributeToFilter on Magento Multiple select attributes.

I have a multiple select attribute for car makes, so the content is 'Audi', 'BMW' and so on. In my example I have a tyre product which I have selected 5 makes for from the multiple select.

I want to display products which have the make 'BMW' as one of their selected fields.

I have tried the following all of which are not working:

```
$products->addAttributeToFilter('make', array('like' => '%BMW%'));  
$products->addFieldToFilter('make', array('like' => '%BMW%'));  
$products->addAttributeToFilter('make', array('like' => '%38%')); // id of the attribute option
```

Nothing seems to work.

Comment: Does $products->addAttributeToFilter(’make’, ‘38’) or $products->addAttributeToFilter('make', array('eq', 38)); give you anything?

Comment: It doesn't work. As it's a multiple select attribute Magento creates 'make' as a string like this: 28,30,35,38 - so if I need to filter the products by BMW which is id 38, then I need it to check all those values.

Comment: Would `finset` me an option? Something like `$products->addAttributeToFilter("make", array("finset"=>"38"));`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The solution is to use a `Find In Set` query such as:

```
$this->_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter("make", array("finset"=>"38"));
```

A discussion can be seen here: [http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/201312/](https://web.archive.org/web/20121228210558/http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/201312/)

And a list of different options: [http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-8-varien-data-collections](https://web.archive.org/web/20121228191909/http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-8-varien-data-collections)

Comment: I found out that this will work for regular drop downs as well, not just a multiselect. I am not sure if there is speed reduction for regular dropdowns or not. tested on ee 1.14.2

Comment: I have to login to vote this answer. Thanks for saving my day.

Answer (score 0):

Try bellow syntax finset it working for me.

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter($attribute,
    array(
        array('finset'=> array('237')),
        array('finset'=> array('238')),
        array('finset'=> array('239')),
    )
);
```